# Using SQL stored procedure to return row of table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL that will return all columns of this table for one row, and that row will match the `snum` argument. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egG7M.png) is the table I'm using.

I know how to find a single row like this:

```
select * from student where snum=578875478;
```

and my thought to do this with a stored procedure was to do this:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists getStudentInfo;
create procedure getStudentInfo(IN sid INT, OUT info VARCHAR(4000)) 
begin 
  select * into info
  from student
  where student.snum=sid;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

My thought here was to match the `snum` with the `sid` and return that whole thing into `info`, but I get an error that says

```
ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

I have to return a row from this table so that it can be used with JDBC and the result can be output to the console in eclipse, but I don't know what to do from here. I've tried to fix this but I'm not understanding the documentation on how this works.

This is my java code as well:

```
package MySQLDemo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Types;

public class SimpleStoreProcedureDemo {

    // info changed for privacy
    static final String databasePrefix ="database";
    static final String netID ="netID";
    static final String hostName ="host";
    static final String databaseURL ="jdbc:mariadb://"+hostName+"/"+databasePrefix;
    static final String password="password";
                
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public void Connection(){

        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("databaseURL"+ databaseURL);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, netID, password);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to the database");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end of Connection

    public void simpleStoreProcedure(String spName) {

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String result = "";
        CallableStatement myCallStmt = connection.prepareCall("{call "+spName+"(?)}");
        myCallStmt.registerOutParameter(1,Types.VARCHAR);
        myCallStmt.execute();
        result = myCallStmt.getString(1);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // end of simpleQuery method
        
public static void main(String args[]) {

    SimpleStoreProcedureDemo demoObj = new SimpleStoreProcedureDemo();
    demoObj.Connection();
    String spName ="getstudentInfo";
    demoObj.simpleStoreProcedure(spName);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for an out parameter or the-like. You can return the resultset directly from the stored procedure, like so:

```
create procedure getStudentInfo(IN p_sid INT) 
select * from student where snum = p_sid;
```

Note that using this technique, you don't even need a `begin`/`end` block, nor to modify the default delimiter.

Comment: That does return the result from the procedure but do I need and out parameter to return a result with jdbc? When I call it through my java code, I get an sqlexception "No output result". I've added my java code

Answer (score 0):

Replace select statement to return `string` instead of a `table` type.Since you have coded to retrieve String output in `jdbc` call info variable should have char datatype.

col1,col2,col3 and col4 are columns of student table,replace as desired.`char(44)` is the comma seperator in the output.

```
 select col1+char(44)+col2+char(44)+col3+char(44)+col4 
 into info
 from student
 where student.snum=sid;
```